# C# Не выводится форма при запуске программы

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите решить проблему, при запуске у меня не запускается форма Form1. в чем может быть проблема?
form1.designer

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательный метод для поддержки конструктора - не изменяйте
    /// содержимое данного метода при помощи редактора кода.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.HostButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.ConnectButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 15);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // HostButton
        // 
        this.HostButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 43);
        this.HostButton.Name = "HostButton";
        this.HostButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 29);
        this.HostButton.TabIndex = 1;
        this.HostButton.Text = "Host";
        this.HostButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.HostButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.HostButton_Click);
        // 
        // ConnectButton
        // 
        this.ConnectButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 78);
        this.ConnectButton.Name = "ConnectButton";
        this.ConnectButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 29);
        this.ConnectButton.TabIndex = 2;
        this.ConnectButton.Text = "Connect";
        this.ConnectButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.ConnectButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ConnectButton_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(146, 121);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ConnectButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.HostButton);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Easy Chat";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button HostButton;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button ConnectButton;
}
```

form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace easy_chat
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.Show();
        }


        private void HostButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            Chat form = new Chat();
            form.StartServer();
            form.Show();
            form1.Close();
        }

        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            Chat form = new Chat();
            IPAddress ip;
            bool isipaddr = IPAddress.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out ip);
            if (isipaddr)
            {
                form.StartClient(ip);
                form.Show();
                form1.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Ip");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace easy_chat
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При запуске а режиме Debug не выдает никаких никаких ошибок, но и не появляется форма. Если же запускать exe файл, то выдает "ошибка при запуске"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в этом куске конструктора:

> ```
> Form1 form = new Form1();
> ```

Comment: я закоментировал эту часть кода, но это не помогло.

Comment: @max619, удали эту и следующую строки.

Comment: @Qwertyi, так и сделал но не помогло

Comment: А нет, ошибся, все заработало. спасибо.